# Drupal 7 Views Question - How to pass 2 arguments

Tags: 7, views

Using Drupal 7, Views 3.

I am attempting to pass a node reference  "department" as first argument via contextual filter.  The department has a number of employees, where I would then want a Views glossary to view by employee name by clicking on a letter.  That is:

Department is Finance, the Views glossary will allow them to choose all employees with last name start with 'A'.  the url will be:

organization/Finance/department/A/staff-listing or in views path, would be
organization/%/department/%/staff-listing

---

I have cloned the glossary view and am able to get the department with employee listing.  However when I click on the glossary letter, the url is changed to organization/A/department/%/staff-listing INSTEAD OF organization/Finance/department/A/staff-listing

When I manually enter the URL ../Finance/department/A/staff-listing , I am getting the right results.  However, when I click on the letter from the glossary, it goes to the first argument.

I appreciate any advice or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know the answer.

I suppose the path to your view without any arguments is "organization".

So first you need to add the contextual filter "department" to the "attachment"-display too. This filter needs to be in first position.

Then:

When filter value is not available > check "Provide default value" > type= Raw value from url> Path component= "2" > save this filter.

Next:

Still inside "attachment"-display open up contextual filter "Content: Title" and change Display a summary > Base path to "organization/%/department/%/staff-listing".

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the detailed explanation.